# Do I need a Provate VPC to Allow Cloud SQL Access from another GCP project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, service-accounts

I currently have the following structure

```
Project 1
Cloud SQL Instance

Project 2
Cloud Run Instance
Service account
```

I would like the project 2 cloud run instance to access the Project 1 Cloud SQL instance.

To do this I...

1. Add the project 2 service account to project 1 and give it permissions.
2. Go into CloudSQL and setup the user and connect to the DB to setup permissions and roles.
3. Try to access CloudSQL instance on the Cloud Run instance using SQL Auth Proxy

But I see posts like this that suggest I should be using a VPC...

[Accessing Cloud SQL from another GCP project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56742056/accessing-cloud-sql-from-another-gcp-project)

But I would really like to avoid managing 2 vpcs for this. Is there a way to do it without VPCs? And based on the post the best option is to pair 2 VPCs?

Comment: You can do it without VPCs. The VPC connection is mandatory (in some way) only if the Cloud SQL instance uses private IP.

Comment: The answer depends on how you have configured Cloud SQL. Those details are not in your question. All Google Cloud projects have a VPC. I am not sure why that is a concern. Additional details are required regarding that concern.

Comment: You can use shared vpc to connect these services using an internal IP address however the requirement for this configuration is that vpc network is included. We also need to consider what @JohnHanley it will also depend on how you configure Cloud SQL

Comment: Ok Sorry guys to clarify one server is using a private ip and one is public. Luckily the one that is private is accessing the public and not vice versa. So I think based on the discussion here I don't need a separate VPC for the public one and I can use firewall rules to provide access to the public one from the private.

Comment: Hi, just wanted to know if this is already resolved by using firewall rules in you setup?

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer for the awareness of other users on what we have discussed in this question. In this scenario we have discussed that firewall rule from this concern is needed to have access from the public server.

I would also like to share this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip) on how you can enable public ip address in cloud sql.