# GCE: access SQL instance in a different project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I currently have a project with a compute instance, connected to a managed Cloud SQL database. When they set it up, they allocated the IP range for the SQL instance and I see it in the current project VPC.

This is a short recap of the IPs and projects I have:

```
proj-existing
    172.30.0.221
sql-in-proj-existing
    10.236.176.10

proj-new
    10.154.0.6
```

VPC name is the same for the two projects.

Now I'd like to be able to access this Cloud SQL instance from `proj-new`. I've read this is possible, but I'm probably missing some pieces.

I think the guide I need to follow is [this one](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-services-access). But I cannot allocate a new subnet with the same address as the existing cloud instance. And it won't let me create a new private link without a subnet.

OTOH, if I add a configuration in *VPC network peering*, it won't turn up because it doesn't have the corresponding peering request on the other end.

So I miss how to create the *Private Service Connection* between `proj-new` and `sql-in-proj-existing`.

Answer (score 1):

As per [bhito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56742056/accessing-cloud-sql-from-another-gcp-project) from a previous post with the same concern, here is the documentation used as [reference](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc-peering) on how to connect Cloud SQL to another project.

It's a must to contact [support](https://cloud.google.com/contact) to manually enable the exchange of custom routes for your Cloud SQL speckle umbrella for it will never work. As of the moment, this process can only be done through contacting support and an ongoing feature request was submitted so it won't need to contact support for enabling the exchange of custom routes

Answer (score 0):

1. **Recommend Using [Private Service Connect](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-service-connect)**: After getting the service attachment URI and using it to create the Private Service Connect endpoint then you may connect directly through an internal IP address.
2. **VPC Peering with Proxy in `sql-in-proj-existing`:**
   Assuming your Cloud SQL instance is created in the `sql-in-proj-existing` project, and you intend to establish a connection from `proj-new`, consider setting up VPC peering between the two projects. Additionally, create a proxy within the `sql-in-proj-existing` project.

   Note: While it's possible to peer three projects (A -> B -> C), direct connectivity from A to C may not be achievable. The Cloud SQL instance is located in a GCP-managed VPC, which implies that it is already peered with your `sql-in-proj-existing` project. That's why we need a proxy in B.
3. **VPN Setup between `sql-in-proj-existing` and `proj-new`:**
   Another approach is to establish a Virtual Private Network (VPN) between the `sql-in-proj-existing` and `proj-new` projects. Comparatively, the first option may be more cost-effective, involving the creation of a proxy VM in the `sql-in-proj-existing` project.